# Azure pipeline yaml mapping fail

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have this pipeline:

```
trigger: none

variables:
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
  - stage:
      job: Test1
      steps:
        - task: UsePythonVersion@0
          inputs:
            versionSpec: '3.x'
            addToPath: true
        - script: |
            python -m pip install --upgrade pip
            pip install selenium
        - task: Pythonscript@0
          inputs:
            scriptSource: 'filePath'
            scriptPath: './script1.py'
  - stage:
      job: Test2
      dependsOn: Test1
      steps:
        - task: UsePythonVersion@0
          inputs:
            versionSpec: '3.x'
            addToPath: true
        - script: |
              python -m pip install --upgrade pip
              pip install selenium
        - task: Pythonscript@0
          inputs:
            scriptSource: 'filePath'
            scriptPath: './script2.py'
```

I would like the job `test2` to run only if the `test1` succeeds. but when I try to run this pipeline I get the error:

```
/azure-pipeline.yaml (Line: 8, Col: 7): A mapping was not expected
/azure-pipeline.yaml (Line: 22, Col: 7): A mapping was not expected
```

The error is in the `job` lines. I don't fully understand why the mapping is not expected if anyone can help me to understand my mistake I will be grateful

Answer (score 1):

Just like `stage` needs to be under a `stages:` block, `job` needs to be under a `jobs:` block

```
stages:
  - stage:
    jobs:
      - job: Test1
```